# Деление чисел в любой системе счисления

Tags: python

Есть ли вариант быстро реализовать деление двух чисел в 16 СС?

Comment: Компьютеру все равно, в какой системе счисления Вы хотите увидеть ответ. По факту он будет делить числа в двоичной

Comment: Просто поделите их, а результат преобразуйте в шестнадцатеричный вид

Answer (score -1):

Да, есть

```
a = любое число
b = любое число
c = a/b
```